# Cordova Background Image Doesn't Work On Android

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I have a problem about background image that doesn't work correctly on my android apps build using cordova. When I run it on browser the background image work perfectly fine, but on the apps it just a blank white background. On below I include my css code.
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgxWG.png), [the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auAjp.png), [result on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuGXC.png), [result on apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loNcq.jpg)

Comment: did you try `img/bag.jpg` ?

Comment: I already try it to put my <style> on my index.html and using background : url(img/bag.jpg), but in the end same result. If i put background : url(img/bag.jpg) on my css, it not work because the image is in other folder outside my css folder.

Comment: thing is its hard to assume the problem without knowing your folder structure. Do you get an error in console when you inspect the device?

Comment: I already edit the question and add the structure image. I'm not using emulator to test the android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below structure

```
www
   -> css
        - style.css

   -> img
        - bag.jpg

   -> index.html
```

**From style.css**

`background:url(../img/bag.jpg);`

**From index.html**

`background:url(img/bag.jpg);`